# List all questions marked as duplicate of a specific post

Tags: discussion, support

For example this question here :

[What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Is there any way to list all the question that are marked as duplicate of this question, or this is not possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All questions that are duped of a question can be seen in the 'Linked Questions' on the side.

If there are a lot of linked posts, they won't all show up there - you have to go to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/218384?sort=newest).

Please note that this includes all linked questions, not just the dupes. AFAIK, there's no way to check just the dupes without using SEDE.

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/613202/duplicates-linked-to-a-post?postid=218384) is the SEDE query.  *(Thanks, @rene!)*

Comment: thank you @Mithrandir this can help me :)

Comment: Here is the [sede query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/613202/duplicates-linked-to-a-post?postid=218384)

Comment: I think this feature could be very useful if one wants to look up just the duplicate questions for more insights.